# Unable to add a partial holiday in Dynamics CRM Service Management

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

[image]I receive an error "Unable to add partial holiday" trying to add a holiday under Dynamics CRM Service Management.Does anyone have a clue what this is?

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Partial holiday schedule can not be createdDetail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
  <ActivityId>c8c662fc-0569-4a87-91e2-8a841a731ff3</ActivityId>
  <ErrorCode>-2147157901</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
  <Message>Partial holiday schedule can not be created</Message>
  <Timestamp>2017-01-19T08:10:24.9843127Z</Timestamp>
  <ExceptionSource i:nil="true" />
  <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
  <OriginalException i:nil="true" />
  <TraceText i:nil="true" />
</OrganizationServiceFault>
```

Comment: Can you download the log file and add it to your question?